# How to put logo a little bit higher and add text above it

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm new in flutter world. I'm trying to put a little bit this logo up and add text above it.

I found that I need `Stack` and `Positioned` Widget to position my logo and sure I can position this logo with i.e: `top: 20, bottom: 20` etc but then I thought, I'm positioning it versus my emulator with certain height and weidth, what about devices with other resolutions? It should be dynamic I guess?

Could you tell me how can I achieve it?
Here is how it should looks:

[image]

How it looks now (dont mind about this logo, it's just an example)

[image]

And my another question. How can I add some text above this logo?

The code I wrote:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEC2C2C2),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('This is My Brand Name',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            FlutterLogo(
              size: 150,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTPqh.jpg

Comment: Could you paste the whole code? I mean what is context and how to adjust this code to mine.

Comment: And could you tell me how does it work? I mena, we got text, then we got empty box which make space between logo and text - I understand that. But how this resize for different resolutions?

Comment: I would use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or (height). you can multiply this with some number that is smaller than 1.(E.g) `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8` this code will give 80% of width to your element. `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15` this code will give 15% of height to your element

Comment: `Image.asset( 'image.png', width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8)` use somthing like this

Comment: okay last question. If I would add buttons then this widget Container cannot be stateless right?

Comment: it depends on what you wanna do.